# How Update the gradle to 3.4.1in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried many thing that is mentioned on the internet but still i am unable to resolve the issue ,while sync it's showing me following error

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

I have changed the gradle-wrapper.properties in gradle of my projectlike this and sync the project

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: create new project and see if prompt for update comes or not.coz i updated today like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> Search for "*Gradle*" to open your gradle settings.

There you need to tick "**Use local gradle distribution**" and point it to the folder where the Gradle binaries live.

In case you haven't done that. Go [here](https://gradle.org/releases) and download the latest Gradle binaries. Extract them somewhere in your machine and add the path of the extraction location as seen in the picture below :)

That should fix it

**EDIT**: This setting works in a "per-project" basis.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

First of all you should add the dependency in Project's `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

And check all repositories groups that they contain `google()` repository:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

After that in `gradle-wrapper.properties` you should change the `distributionUrl`:

`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade your version **com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.** is not found in **https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/** repository.

Include the below classpath in your respective module.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Or Download the latest gradle through the below
 link

**https://gradle.org/releases**

and include the directory in your project setting.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to let Android Studio update a whole bunch of things like adding google to the repositories, upgrading the gradle wrapper and moving the android minsdk version from the manifest into gradle.  Now it synced fine :)