# Gradle sync failed. Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I download basicSample project from below link of GitHub. When I want to sync project, I get below error. I searched and a i saw this link ([How Update the gradle to 3.4.1in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701773/how-update-the-gradle-to-3-4-1in-android-studio)), i try offline mode but again not worked. I was confused. Can't i sync gradle 3.4.0 online? Should i used offline sync? If yes how i set gradle and gradle plugin (I set path of gradle in settings but Android studio shows below message)?

```
  No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 available for offline mode.
  Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Github link:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample

Error for sync gradle 3.4.0 for online mode:

```
 Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
```

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
  - http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
  - http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File

Comment: Make sure you have an active internet connection while syncing the project with a Gradle version which was not cached on your system earlier. You can try setting an older version of Gradle in your Project Settings ( File -> Project Structure )

Comment: I have no problem for connection. I have proxy because these services is blocked in my country :( but i don't think that was for internet connection. How can i work offline? I don't want downgrade gradle

Comment: @FahimehHashemian Please look at my answer for a possible solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701773/how-update-the-gradle-to-3-4-1in-android-studio/57381688#57381688

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution.**

Follow the step to solve your problem.

1. Go to **File** option.
2. Click On **Settings** option. (Ctrl + Alt + S)
3. There is an open new popup window, look at the left panel of that window.
4. Expand **Build, Execution, Deployment** option.
5. Click on **Gradle** option.
6. Uncheck **Offline work**, Click Apply -> Ok.
7. Sync the project.

As you can see in below pic.

[image]